# Problema al instalar @react-navigation/stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-navigation, stack

Cuando quiero instalar:

```
npm install @react-navigation/stack
npm install @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Me sale este error, no se si sea la versión del react.
[image: Error al instalar @react-native-community/masked-vie]

Este es mi package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-screens": "^2.18.1"
```

},

Comment: crea tu proyecto con npx create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

para instalar paquetes a pesar de los conflictos de peerDependencies, puedes usar el flag `--legacy-peer-deps` justo después de `npm install`.

npm install --legacy-peer-deps

También pudieras agregar `--force` para forzar la instalación, justo como te lo esta diciendo ahí.

[Fuente](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major)

Comment: Gracias funcionó con `--legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado lo mismo usando expo y la solución fue eliminar `node_moudles` y volver a ejecutar `npm install`, luego `npm install react-navigation`

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el problema borrando la carpeta `node_modules` y el archivo `package-lock.json` y después ejecutado nuevamente

```
npm install
```